# How enable a button after save (Response.Redirect) a excel file in vb.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

[image]

I have a form like in image. I want after i click CREATE BOM to activate Button Create Order but i have a problem, if i write that in my button: `BTN_CreateSample.Enabled = True` is ok, but doesn't finish post back and after i save my button Create Order doesn't be Enabled.

My code are:

```
 Protected Sub BTN_CreateBOM_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BTN_CreateBOM.Click

        BTN_CreateSample.Enabled = True



        Dim SampleOrder As String = BOX_SampleOrder.Text

        SampleOrder = SampleOrder.Remove(0, 3)

        Dim cn As New OleDbConnection
        Dim cm As New OleDbCommand
        cn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & Server.MapPath("../../TempDownloads/Template_BOM.xlsx") & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES""")
        cn.Open()
        With cm
            .Connection = cn
            .CommandText = "UPDATE [ARO list$] set info = 'SO-300' where [SO-info] ='DVM SO no.'"
            cm = New OleDbCommand(.CommandText, cn)
            cm.ExecuteNonQuery()
            cn.Close()

            cn.Open()
            .CommandText = "UPDATE [ARO list$] set info = 'SO-301' where [SO-info] ='Local SO no.'"
            cm = New OleDbCommand(.CommandText, cn)
            cm.ExecuteNonQuery()
            cn.Close()

            cn.Open()
            .CommandText = "UPDATE [ARO list$] set info = 77 where [SO-info] ='qty'"
            cm = New OleDbCommand(.CommandText, cn)
            cm.ExecuteNonQuery()
            cn.Close()
        End With

        Try
            My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(
        Server.MapPath("../../TempDownloads/Template_BOM.xlsx"),
        Server.MapPath("../../TempDownloads/" & SampleOrder & ".xlsx"), Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.UIOption.AllDialogs, Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.UICancelOption.DoNothing)
        Catch ex As Exception
            LBL_Error.ForeColor = Color.Red
            LBL_Error.Text = "This SO is already registred !"
            LBL_Status.Text = Nothing
            Exit Sub
        End Try
        CreateSampleOrder.Visible = True

        Response.Redirect("../../ScriptDownload/Download.aspx?FileP=" + HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlEncode(Server.MapPath("../../TempDownloads/" & SampleOrder & ".xlsx")))

    End Sub
```

I want a postback or i don't know, when i arrive at Response.Redirect to continue my button and refresh page to Enabled my button Crate Order, he stay stuck after i press Create BOM. Thanks

Comment: Is the sub exiting via the catch ex as exception path? If so the creatsampleorder.visible = true will not be called.

Comment: Also you mentioned you want createsample to be enabled, but only actually enable createorder - is this a type in the question? At the moment you can't ENABLE the 'createsampleorder' button.